# NSMutableattributed string not working for substring

Tags: ios, nsmutableattributedstring

```
-(NSMutableAttributedString *)getAttributedStringforString:(NSString *)totalString filtertext:(NSString *)filtertext font:(UIFont *)titlefont backgroundColor:(UIColor *)bcolor foregroundColor:(UIColor *)fcolor
{
    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = nil;
    NSDictionary *filterTextAttribute = @{NSBackgroundColorAttributeName:bcolor, NSForegroundColorAttributeName:fcolor, NSFontAttributeName: titlefont};
    attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:totalString];
    [attributedString beginEditing];
    [attributedString setAttributes:filterTextAttribute range:[totalString rangeOfString:filtertext options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch]];
    [attributedString endEditing];

    return attributedString;
}
```

I am applying `NSMutableAttributedString` for filtertext in totalstring if filtertext  is totalstring then the above setattributes is working otherwise its not working for substrings

Comment: I have tried so many posts in stackoverflow which is similar to this qiestion but none of the answers are working for me

Comment: Start by checking the range you are applying the attributes to, so calculate that in the line before setting the attributes and examine it in the debugger.

Comment: So the range is correct?

Comment: The answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520544/applying-different-attributes-for-different-portions-of-an-nsattributedstring) seems to suggest you need to use the `CGColor` of the `UIColor` object to specify the colours, however that is not what the reference says.  Might be worth a try though...

Comment: There seems to be nothing wrong in that way you are setting the string. I tried out the same code, and it works.. In the case in which it doesn't work, What is the totalString and filterString value that you are using?

Comment: I am using it in cellforrowatindex path method i am passing total string as "Cestrol 175ml RB" and filtertext is "estrol".